# Stuck on Concatenation array formula with multiple criteria

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a formula which worked quite well to obtain information in order to link a reference contained in column B with information in T column of Sheet 2.

I have a formula which checks if 'Sheet2'!B:B=B2. However, now I want the formula to only return information where the corresponding line also has "yes" in Column A.

For example, if B2=1001, I only want to return CAT in the example below:

[image]

Is it possible to have two criteria like this?

I have tried various AND formulas alongside the main formula I have but this brings back errors:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A4),"",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ⦿",TRUE,IF('Sheet2'!B:B=B2,'Sheet2'!T:T,""))))
```

I need to put somewhere in this formula to check if A2="Yes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A4),, ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ⦿", 1 , 
 IF((Sheet2!A:A="yes")*(Sheet2!B:B=B2), Sheet2!T:T, ))))
```

[image: 0]